# Shiny Dashboard: Attempt to save the state and rerun the dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

We have a shiny dashboard which has been arrived at after performing some transformation on the a data frame, say a contingency table, or a plot is generated from this data frame and added to dashboard. These visualisation and tables added to dashboard are interactive and can have filters, etc...

Wanted to know if there is any opinionated way or prescribed way of saving this dashboard with its state, close the application and then reopen the dashboard with the state which was prior to save.

Right now we are looking at saving the state information about each component in JSON, on how it was arrived at, and what filters were chosen, etc.. 
So that while reopening the dashboard, this JSON would be read and processed to create the same state.
Please advise.

Comment: Most of the dashboard applications should be connected to some database. To scale your app its best if you set-up a DB in the background. You can save the states based on the user login

Comment: Have you looked at bookmarkable state: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html? Is this not sufficient for you?

Comment: Thanks @BárbaraBorges, I shall take a look at the bookmarkable state and if that suffices our requirement.